# Selenium: Testing interaction between users on different browsers

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, chat, selenium-rc

I am implementing a suite to test the behavior of a chat. Each user performs different actions to log in into the chat on different browsers.

I have implemented each test case separately and work fine. I also implemented one suite which includes both cases, one first and then the other and it runs but it looks like both browsers are not sharing the information, because it does not show the user logged in. Here is an example of that I am implementing in java:

public class connect_facebook extends SeleneseTestCase{

```
Selenium sele1 = null;
Selenium sele2 = null;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
//Establish the first browser
sele1 = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.google.es/");
//Establish the second browser
sele2 = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*googlechrome " , "http://www.facebook.com");
//Start the first test case
sele1.start();
//Start the second test case
sele2.start();

}

//Send the message to a friend in Facebook
@Test
public void testConnect_facebook_nocookies() throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

I don't stop sele1

```
//Open Facebook, check the message and open Zaraproxy to start Connect
@Test
public void testCheck_mail_facebook() throws Exception {
    ...
```

}

NOTE: What it does is at the very beginning opens FF and Chrome, then closes Chrome and runs sele1. After that does not close FF but opens another FF and Chome browser, closes FF and then runs sele2 with Chrome.

When sele2 opens the chat panel, the user of sele1 (FF) appears offline.

I am using selenium server as a HUB and started another server as a node (not using selenium grid). Want to resolve with selenium RC first before passing to selenium Grid because installation of the Grid have been given me some problems.

Any help is welcome! Thanks in advance!

B